# mt.exe unable to terminate

Tags: windows, build, msbuild, compilation, manifest

Sometimes when I compile C++ code using nmake, the build process gets stuck at the manifest tool mt.exe (see the bottom of this screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgyzT.png). It just never finishes, but if I cancel the build process and start again, it may run past the last point but get stuck again at another seemingly random mt.exe process. This makes building big software very cumbersome, as I need to "monitor" the build process to know when to cancel and start again from the beginning.

I'm clueless as to what could be the reason to this behavior. Has anybody encountered this problem before?

Edit: I'm using Windows 8 x64, the mt.exe comes from Windows SDK 6.0A.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with msbuild getting stuck at random points. Never found out what caused it, but a workaround that worked for me was to disable parallel building of projects.

Answer (score 0):

Trying disabling your anti-virus on-demand scanning when building. I have seen some anti-virus software block access to a file using mt.exe, though usually you get an error instead of a hang.